# Who are considered the last true polymaths of math and science

Tags: polymath

Rather it be within a single discipline and the sub fields within it. Or completely different scientific fields. People that had significant contributions in many fields?

Who are some of the most prominent polymaths before the era of specialization truly kicked in?

Comment: In mathematics it was said David Hilbert was among the last.

Comment: John von Neumann is perhaps also a good nomination. What about John H. Conway? And are 'polyhistors' (like Arnold J. Toynbee) to be included here?

Comment: Looking through Alexander Ostrowski's Collected Papers recently, I was impressed by the vast range of his contributions.

Comment: [Roger Penrose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Penrose) is still alive.

Comment: I'd read that Poincare was considered such.